# android fragment inside listview

Tags: android

my app is a social network where users share links and tag them to let the right persons receive it. Basically, the main activity is simply a listview of posts. I use an open protocol parser to get the web objects metadata on server side.

Now I need to display the right layout in each post item depending of the metadata (video, app, web page, ...). And of course, layouts must react to user clicks event and call intents.

So my first idea is to have a framelayout for each item where I load a specific fragment in charge of generating the right layout depending of the resource type.

But I'm really not sure loading a fragment inside a listview item is a good practice as the reuse system of views is totally messed up.

I'd just like to know what is the best way to implement this functionality for you guys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really what fragments are designed for. You do not need to use fragments to have `ListView` rows of differing types -- just override `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` in your `ListAdapter`, then be sure to create the right type of row on demand based upon the metadata.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare, I'll go for it even I'd have preferred to have a nice way to do it instead of giving the adapter the whole responsibility to generate the view. Something like a view factory for instance.

Comment: @mth.vidal: There is nothing stopping you from delegating the work of row construction to a "view factory", though I tend to think of the adapter itself *being* the "view factory". Fragments are not really a "view factory", IMHO, though that may just be a difference in opinion on the use of the phrase.

Comment: I found a nice solution from this article : http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/

Comment: It should be possible to put fragments inside anything.  It's absurd to have to refactor between a View and a Fragment just because you want to put it in something else.

Comment: @GlennMaynard: `ListView` was written many years before fragments existed. You are welcome to write a `FragmentListView` that supports the notion of fragments as list rows.

Comment: It's Google's job to provide a sane, self-consistent framework for developers.  It's not my job to roll my own because Google's APIs are missing basic things.

Comment: @GlennMaynard: All platforms and frameworks have gaps. If you don't like Android's particular gaps, then don't write for Android, just as if somebody doesn't like Django's gaps, they can skip using Django.